# Cherrypy 3.2.0 : starting engine to run both HTTP and HTTPS in th same instance

Tags: http, python-3.x, https, cherrypy

Good morning,

I successfully start cherrypy 3.2.0 engine in HTTP OR HTTPS :

```
# ssl variable commes input parameters. Bellow cherrypy configuration is fully configured

if ssl:
    print('Setting up SSL')
    cherrypy.server.ssl_certificate = "conf/private/" + platform.node() + ".crt"
    cherrypy.server.ssl_private_key = "conf/private/" + platform.node() + ".key"


'''
----------------------------------
Start server instance
----------------------------------
'''
if hasattr(cherrypy.engine, 'block'):
    # 3.1 syntax
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
else:
    # 3.0 syntax
    cherrypy.server.quickstart(cherrypy.root, config=py_app_conf)
    cherrypy.engine.start()
```

So, is it possible to configure cherrypy to start both in http AND https in the same cherrypy server ?

Thanks for ypur reply.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have two servers on different ports: [Multiple servers/ports](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/process/servers.html#multiple-servers-ports). Also there is a multi-server config feature that seems to be undocumented, see if it works for you, refer to `_server_namespace_handler()` function in `_cpconfig.py`.

Comment: Repaired link: http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/advanced.html#multiple-http-servers-support

Comment: @EricSmith It may be outdated now, but what I originally suggested is now documented at [cherrypy.process.servers.ServerAdapter](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.process.html#cherrypy.process.servers.ServerAdapter).