# cherrypy two servers different ports

Tags: python, cherrypy

I want to run 2 servers of cherry py on different ports and with a different application.

I manage to run them both, but how do i connect between the app's and the servers ?
I want to be able to go to

`http://127.0.0.1:3141/`
and get `server1`
and to

`http://127.0.0.1:3145/`
and get `server2`

cherrypy docs example for multiple servers is not good enough for me to understand how to do this.
here it is [Multiple servers/ports](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/process/servers.html#multiple-servers-ports)

my code

```
import cherrypy

class App1(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
         return ('server1')

class App2(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
         return ('server2')


cherrypy.server.unsubscribe()

server1 = cherrypy._cpserver.Server()
server1.socket_port=3141
server1._socket_host="127.0.0.1"
server1.thread_pool=2
server1.subscribe()

server2 = cherrypy._cpserver.Server()
server2.socket_port=3145
server2._socket_host="127.0.0.1"
server2.thread_pool=2
server2.subscribe()

cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

Comment: Dupe--see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581342/cherrypy-3-2-0-starting-engine-to-run-both-http-and-https-in-th-same-instance/20581885#20581885

Comment: @jwalker i have seen the docs and the example for the two server is short and i lacking the information i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your apps need to (or can) be served from different paths (e. g. `http://127.0.0.1:3141/app1` and `http://127.0.0.1:3145/app2`), just use [`tree.mount()`](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/_cptree.html#cherrypy._cptree.Tree.mount) for each app. If both apps must be served from the root path, look at [VirtualHost](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/_cpwsgi.html?highlight=vhost#cherrypy._cpwsgi.VirtualHost) for an idea.

Comment: how do you connect between tree.mount and a server ?

Comment: @yossi If they are not automatically connected when you start it all, try using HTTPServer or CherryPyWSGIServer.

Comment: I'm afraid this still doesn't make it clear how to mount one application to one server and another application to another server.

Comment: @DrMickeyLauer Will your apps be serving from different paths? Yes: just use `ServerAdapter` as per [Multiple servers/ports](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.2.6/refman/process/servers.html#multiple-servers-ports). No: add [VirtualHost](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.2.6/refman/_cpwsgi.html?highlight=virtualhost#cherrypy._cpwsgi.VirtualHost).

Answer (score 0):

After tweaking for a while I was not able to mount each app to a specific port.
The behavior was that each port was responding to each app, so I added a tool to filter port on each app as shown in the example below:

```
import cherrypy
from cherrypy._cpserver import Server


@cherrypy.tools.register('before_handler')
def port_filter():
    if cherrypy.request.app.root.request_port != cherrypy.request.local.port:
        raise cherrypy.NotFound()


class App1(object):
    def __init__(self, request_port):
        self.request_port = request_port

    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.port_filter()
    def index(self):
        return "Hello world from app1"


class App2(object):
    def __init__(self, request_port):
        self.request_port = request_port

    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.port_filter()
    def index(self):
        return "Hello world from app2"


class MyServer(Server):
    def __init__(self, host, port, thread_pool=10):
        Server.__init__(self)
        self.socket_port = port
        self._socket_host = host
        self.thread_pool = thread_pool
        self.subscribe()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Unsubscribe default server
    cherrypy.server.unsubscribe()

    # Setup server for each port
    MyServer(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
    MyServer(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)

    # Mount applications to specific port
    cherrypy.tree.mount(App1(80), "/app1")
    cherrypy.tree.mount(App2(8080), "/app2")

    # Start!
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need two different directory. In each directory/app you put a config file for the app.
For example i have something like this:

```
[global]
server.socket_host = "ip_address"
server.socket_port = 8080
server.thread_pool = 10


[/]
tools.staticdir.root = "/path/to/your/app"
tools.encode.on = True
tools.decode.on = True
```

Have a look [here](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/config.html?highlight=configuration%20file)

Comment: yeah but how do i connect between app and a server ?

Comment: Sorry, what you mean? Did you start your application by run in a shell the command: `python your_script.py`?

Comment: my code create two server instance i just need a way to connect an app to each of them

Comment: If you mean connect the same app to 2 different servers i don't know if it's possible. If you mean connect 2 different app to 2 different server, i don't know as well :-) I use different approach with cherrypy. I have a directory for each app, in the directory i have MyApp1.py and MyApp1.conf, so i just launch in a shell `python MyApp1.py` and server instance start to listening on port 8080 (based on the file posted here) giving the directory content specified by `[/]
tools.staticdir.root = "/path/to/your/app"`. Like this for each directory.
Sory if i can't help you more.